# how to use Request.QueryString in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, .net

In aspx page I have anchor tags. My URL already has Id parameter which I want to reuse.
Requirement is to redirect user to a mentioned page with current url id e.g.

```
"~/Dir/Home?Id=" & Request.QueryString
```

Please note I have to do this in aspx page as cant use code behind pages.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

You can use scriptlets

```
'~/Dir/Home?Id=<%= Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["ID"]) %>';
```

You can learn more about using QueryString [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use like this

```
'~/Dir/Home?Id=<%Request.QueryString.Get("ID")??""%>'
```

Similar question on SO
[how to retrieve a querystring value from an .aspx page and pass it to ascx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621703/how-to-retrieve-a-querystring-value-from-an-aspx-page-and-pass-it-to-ascx-page)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1655117.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way is to add a name attribute to the iframe tag:

```
<iframe runat="server" id="frameid" name="framename" src="anypage.aspx"></iframe>
```

and then add this on the page_load event:

```
framename.Attributes.Item("src") = "thepage.aspx?id=" & Request.querystring("id")
```

Easy, clean and in VBNET no JavaScript needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
href="contact_list.aspx?xid=<%= Request.QueryString["xeroID"].ToString()%>"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.